# Working out the shape/formula result of combining two segments on different planes

Tags: geometry

Given a pipe that starts at $(0,0,0)$ that curves on the horizontal plane with a radius of $400$ and curves on the vertical plane with a radius of $200$, would the resultant line be a segment of an ellipse if you laid it down flat?

As far as I can work out the constraint for this line would be:

$x^2 + (y-200)^2 = 200^2$ as the vertical plane component
where $x > 0$ and $y < 200$

$z^2 + (x+400)^2 = 400^2$ as the horizontal plane component
where $z > -400$ and $x > 0$ again

I'm not sure how I would combine these properly and whether there would even be 1 answer or if it would be a range of answers?

Comment: I could be wrong but I believe the curvatures are non-interacting. I do not believe that laying the curve down flat (top view) would yield anything more than the horizontal curve, a circle segment with a radius of 400.

Comment: How can you lay it down flat if it has 3 dimensions? Do you mean a *projection* on the third orthogonal plane?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is a true 3D curve, not a planar one. It is actually shaped much like your lips are, when smiling.

---

You have a pair of equations:
$$\left\lbrace\begin{aligned}
x^2 + (y - 200)^2 - 200^2 &= 0 \\
z^2 + (x + 400)^2 - 400^2 &= 0 \\
\end{aligned}\right.\tag{1a}\label{NA1a}$$
You can solve this for $y$ and $z$. Given that $0 \le x \le 200$, we get
$$\left\lbrace\begin{aligned}
y &= 200 \pm \sqrt{x^2 - 200} \\
z &= \pm \sqrt{x (800 - x)} \\
\end{aligned}\right.\tag{1b}\label{NA1b}$$

We can parametrize this closed curve for $0 \le t \le 1$ thus:
$$\begin{aligned}
x(t) &= \begin{cases}
200 - 800 t, & 0 \le t \le \frac{1}{4} \\
800 t - 200, & \frac{1}{4} \le t \le \frac{2}{4} \\
600 - 800 t, & \frac{2}{4} \le t \le \frac{3}{4} \\
800 t - 600, & \frac{3}{4} \le t \le 1 \\
\end{cases} \\
y(t) &= \begin{cases}
200 + \sqrt{200^2 - x^2}, & 0 \le t \le \frac{1}{2} \\
200 - \sqrt{200^2 - x^2}, & \frac{1}{2} \le t \le 1 \\
\end{cases} \\
z(t) &= \begin{cases}
\sqrt{x (800 - x)}, & 0 \le t \le \frac{1}{4} \; \text{or} \; \frac{3}{4} \le t \le 1 \\
-\sqrt{x (800 - x)}, & \frac{1}{4} \le t \le \frac{3}{4} \\
\end{cases} \\
\end{aligned}\tag{2a}\label{NA2a}$$
i.e.
$$\begin{aligned}
x(t) &= \begin{cases}
200 - 800 t, & 0 \le t \le \frac{1}{4} \\
800 t - 200, & \frac{1}{4} \le t \le \frac{2}{4} \\
600 - 800 t, & \frac{2}{4} \le t \le \frac{3}{4} \\
800 t - 600, & \frac{3}{4} \le t \le 1 \\
\end{cases} \\
y(t) &= \begin{cases}
200 + 400\sqrt{2 t (1 - 2 t)}, & 0 \le t \le \frac{2}{4} \\
200 - 400\sqrt{2 (1 - 2 t)(t - 1)}, & \frac{2}{4} \le t \le 1 \\
\end{cases} \\
z(t) &= \begin{cases}
-200 \sqrt{-16 t^2 - 8 t + 3}, & 0 \le t \le \frac{2}{4} \\
200 \sqrt{-16 t^2 + 24 t - 5}, & \frac{1}{4} \le t \le \frac{2}{4} \\
200 \sqrt{-16 t^2 + 8 t + 3}, & \frac{2}{4} \le t \le \frac{3}{4} \\
-200 \sqrt{-16 t^2 + 40 t - 21}, & \frac{3}{4} \le t \le 1 \\
\end{cases} \\
\end{aligned}\tag{2b}\label{NA2b}$$

For simple illustration, you can use e.g. Awk to generate a file containing 800 samples (at regular intervals in $x$). For example,

```
awk 'BEGIN { \
     for (x = 200; x > 0;    x--) printf "%f %f %d\n", x, 200+sqrt(200*200-x*x), -sqrt(x*(800-x)); \
     for (x = 0;   x < 200;  x++) printf "%f %f %f\n", x, 200+sqrt(200*200-x*x), +sqrt(x*(800-x)); \
     for (x = 200; x > 0;    x--) printf "%f %f %d\n", x, 200-sqrt(200*200-x*x), +sqrt(x*(800-x)); \
     for (x = 0;   x <= 200; x++) printf "%f %f %f\n", x, 200-sqrt(200*200-x*x), -sqrt(x*(800-x)); \
     }' > 'output.txt'
```

You can then use e.g. Gnuplot to visualize the curve in 3D. Start Gnuplot, and run

```
splot "output.txt" u 1:2:3 notitle w lines lc -1
```

This gives you an interactive window to examine the curve. Both GNU awk (gawk) and gnuplot are available for basically all operating systems. (Windows users, check out [ezwinports](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ezwinports/) for gawk, and [Tatsuro Matsuoka](http://www.tatsuromatsuoka.com/gnuplot/Eng/winbin/)s Windows installers for gnuplot. They are free and open software, so anyone can compile them for their own system if they want.)